# Visual Studio 2015 - JavaScript Intellisense not working after using a Promise

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015

Why does Intellisense not work inside the continuation of a promise in Visual Studio 2015?

It works fine in the method, inside the "try" portion of the promise, the catch block of the promise, but it does not work in the "then" continuation. I would expect it to see the variables from the enclosing scope. See comments below.

```js
    // Initialize View Models
    var vm = {
        boards: ko.observableArray([]),
        cards: [],
        currentBoard: null,
        selectBoard: selectBoard
    };

  function updateDataToService() {
         // Intellisense works here (e.g., vm.xxx )
    
        Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
            var names = ctx.workbook.names;
            var range = names.getItem('MyRange').getRange();
            range.load('address');
            // Intellisense works here (e.g., range.xxx, vm.xxx )
          
            return ctx.sync().then(function() {
                // Intellisense DOES NOT WORK HERE
                // (e.g., range.xxx, ctx.xxx, vm.xxx)
                // ALL DO NOT WORK
              
                console.log(range.address);
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Intellisense works here (e.g., error.xxx, vm.xxx)
          
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, it looks like the `return` is confusing it, thinking that any code after that is not runnable so doesn't do anything? I get similar things but just put up with it, so can't think of particular cases. Clearly a bug of some sort, maybe worth raising on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio)

Comment: If you were to define a variable inside the function called by then, would it get intellisence. I was wondering if there was some weird scoping issue going on.

Comment: @DogPawHat All of the intellisense is gone inside the then() block. Regardless of defined local or defined in the outer scope.